# Can I cross-post the same question in both Super User and Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, stackexchange, etiquette

Is it bad Stack Exchange etiquette to ask a duplicate of an Ask Ubuntu question on Super User and vice versa? (Assuming of course that said question is relevant on both sites.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The last time we discussed this *we* didn't really have a problem (people getting problems solved is the priority) but *most* other stackexchange websites don't allow cross-posting.

The [official line from upon high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073) is to pick the best site and post there and only there. Write the best question you possibly can and if it doesn't pay off, ask for it to be migrated.

Comment: OK, I was feeling a little guilty.  I'll delete the unanswered question.

Comment: (I finally posted the same question verbatim on Super user in frustration a while back and got a lot of answers in a little time.)

Comment: Oh great, I can only vote to delete it.  Time to wait for a mod! **hint hint** =D

Comment: If you "vote" to delete your own question, it's *deleted* for all intents and purposes. Only you can undelete it, or mods/10k+ users--who are the only ones that can even see it--can reopen/vote to reopen.

Comment: Oh!  Okay then, thanks!