# Is there some convention or etiquette about asking the same question in different fora?

Tags: discussion

Both askubuntu.com and ubuntuforums.org are wonderful resources. I've noticed that people sometimes post their questions at both sites mostly without mentioning that they have done so.

While it's understandable to want an answer ASAP, is there some convention or etiquette involving cross-posting?

I've seen this question: [Can I cross-post the same question in both Super User and Ask Ubuntu?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3536/can-i-cross-post-the-same-question-in-both-super-user-and-ask-ubuntu) and hope it's not a duplicate because that one was limited to Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: You are correct. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: From what I understand, the convention is to pick one and only one, but I may misunderstand. I'm biased of course, I think Ask Ubuntu is the better of the two. ;P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a cross site convention, and if there was, how would you enforce it?

I think if you find one just go ahead and edit in a link to the forum post, and if you see an answer there then post it (linking with proper attribution) so that it'll at least act as a sign post for the next person.

Comment: I've been doing that (on occasion).