# What is the etiquette for posting the same answer to multiple Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, etiquette

I recently found that the same question - How to speed up video on Linux – had been asked on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134576/how-can-i-change-the-speed-of-a-video/) and on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/160432/speedup-a-video-on-linux/). I gave the same answer on both.

In cases such as these, where the same question has been asked on multiple sites by different users, should the same answer be posted on each site?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I cross-post the same question in both Super User and Ask Ubuntu?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3536/can-i-cross-post-the-same-question-in-both-super-user-and-ask-ubuntu)

Comment: Scratch that, not a duplicate... But the information in that post still applies.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same question, you should **ask for it to be migrated** to the appropriate site. For instance, an Ubuntu question may well be on topic at SuperUser, but it should ideally be on AU.

Google is the User interface. Having a question in multiple places does not increase its visibility.

Comment: Would users on Unix.SE and Super User agree that Ubuntu questions are always better posted on Ask Ubuntu than on their sites?

Comment: @EliahKagan Maybe it is time to pay a visit to [meta.unix.se] and ask?