# Should I ask and answer a question that I feel would be useful on Ask Ubuntu, but that's already on Super User?

Tags: discussion

A while back I had a problem with bash, which I then Googled and solved.

There's already a question on Super User with my problem. That being said, I feel like it would be valuable information to have on Ask Ubuntu. Should I ask (and then answer) a duplicate of the Super User question on Ask Ubuntu? I did see [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/47/how-do-we-tell-if-a-question-belongs-here-or-rather-at-stackoverflow-superuser?rq=1), and I think that it would definitely be on topic here if it weren't on Super User.

I also saw [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3536/can-i-cross-post-the-same-question-in-both-super-user-and-ask-ubuntu), which makes me lean more towards the answer "no". However, it still seems like a grey area to me. Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not cross-posting, unless *the same person* asks the question there and here. (It might also be considered cross-posting if *the exact same text* were posted both there and here. While technically not cross-posting, that would be bad.) Furthermore, the issue is not whether or not the question is *on-topic* there or here--it's on-topic in both places. So neither of the meta questions you've mentioned are likely to be of much help in deciding this one.

I'm not sure what would be accomplished by having it in both places. If someone posts the question here without having realized it was on Super User, that means there is a need *here* (at least that one person's need). Then it can be answered here. One way it could be answered here would be by quoting from and linking to the answer to the corresponding question on Super User.

If nobody's asked it here, that suggests that Ubuntu users who have had this problem have searched and found the answer (on Super User, or elsewhere). That suggests it doesn't need to be here.

Asking a question here with the intention of answering it yourself is generally fine--there is even a checkbox when you ask a question, that lets you compose the answer at the same time and submit them together. However, when you ask and answer a question here intentionally, it should *add a useful new resource to the Internet*. I doesn't necessarily need to add new information in the strictest sense--it's okay of the information is *possible* to get elsewhere. But it should carry some substantial benefit compared to other available Internet resources.

It sounds like you're just talking about copying content. Unless you think the question or answer will be *deleted* on Super User, there's probably no good reason to do that. You might want to save the web page from Super User *in case* something like that happens. Then (with proper attribution) it could be posted here or elsewhere (though you should of course first consider the reason it was deleted there in case that were to impact its suitability in other places).

Answer (score 4):

Cross posting is kinda frowned on the network in most cases - both questions would turn up on search engines. People *will* find it.

On the *other hand* If you have a *remarkably similar* problem, and *happen* to cite the SU question when going into your own specific problem, and self answer, it *so happens* it might not look like you're crossposting at all and there's no duplicate on AU... so that might work.

Comment: So if I have a similar but not exact duplicate, I maybe can?

Comment: @strugee If you basically only transfer information, make your posts Community Wikis.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the people reach Super User and Ask Ubuntu via search engines. So an Ubuntu user has an equal probability of getting an answer from Super User as from Ask Ubuntu. So there is no need of copy-pasting Super User posts here.